# Code::Blocks undefined reference

Tags: codeblocks

I am working on the first chapter of the OpenGLBook and everything works fine until I add the code for "Adding GLEW".

I get following errors:

> obj\Debug\main.o||In function `Initialize':|
>
> C:\Projects\test\main.c|35|undefined reference to `*imp*_glewInit@0'|
>
> C:\Projects\test\main.c|38|undefined reference to
>   `*imp*_glewGetErrorString@4'|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

I have these libraries set up in the linker:

> libfreeglut.a
>
> glew32.lib
>
> OpenGL32.Lib
>
> freeglut.lib
>
> GlU32.Lib
>
> libfreeglut_static.a

They are in that order.

How can I fix this so I can continue to learn?